# Protect user edited *.desktop files from upgrades

Tags: upgrade, .desktop

I like to edit `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` files (fortunately, just a few of them) to fit my needs. When the relative application is updated, though, those edits I made get lost. How should I face this inconvenience?

One possibility is to keep a separate version of the `*.desktop` files, so **the question** is *where should I put my edited versions to have them have the precedence over the original versions in `/usr/share/applications/`*?

As a side question: It's crystal clear that I should check, from time to time, if some important change was made to the original file and pick up those changes manually, if needed. What is a possible approach in this respect?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? Depending on whether you're using debs or rpms, there might be ways to divert the files specific to each package manager...

Comment: The location for desktop files for a user is `~/.local/share/applications` so maybe try that one if you want a user-specific override...

Comment: I use Arch. Tag added accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take, as hinted at by [Filipe Brandenburger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/281844/filipe-brandenburger):

- install your modified `.desktop` file in another location, which will be preferred to `/usr/share/applications` — typically, `/usr/local/share/applications` for `.desktop` overrides which apply to all users, or `~/.local/share/applications` for user-specific overrides (or overrides on systems where you’re not able to edit the contents of `/usr/local/share/applications`);
- override the distribution-provided files by diverting them.

I would take the first approach. See [the Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html) for details.

Once you’ve edited your files, you can compare them against the originals provided by your distribution using tools such as `diff` or Meld. You could also store copies of the originals which you used as a base, to see what changed between successive packaged versions. You could do all this with a VCS if you’re used to working like that.